# C malloc: ordering statements to produce errors

Tags: c, memory-management

I need help checking if my answers to an exercise are correct.

I am given the following statements (p,q have type char*):

```
a. free(p);
b. free(q);
c. p = q;
d. q = nullptr;
e. p = (char*) malloc(12);
f. q = (char*) malloc(8);
g. p[8] = 0;
h. q[4] = 0;
```

Question 1: Put the statements in an order that would execute without error or evoking undefined behavior. Memory leaks count as errors.

My solution: e,f,g,h,a,b,c,d. In retrospect, d,c,e,f,g,h,a,b would be the more logical ordering but is the one before still correct?

Question 2: Put the statements in an order that would cause one double-free error, and no other error or undefined behavior (except possibly one memory leak).

My solution: e,f,g,h,c,a,b,d. Once again, I am reusing a pointer after free, is this valid?

Question 3: Put the statements in an order that would cause one memory leak (one allocated piece of memory is not freed), and no other error or undefined behavior. Use each statement exactly once.

My solution: d,b,e,f,g,h,c,a.

Question 4: Put the statements in an order that would cause one boundary write error, and no other error or undefined behavior. Use each statement exactly once.

My solution : e,f,a,c,g,h,b,d.

Comment: There are expression in that code that *isn't* C, but C++. Which makes this a rather bad C++ question actually.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Each expression in the code can be fully defined C, given suitable definitions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil True, but then that would make it a pretty bad C question. Either way, it's a bad assignment. And since there are multiple possible "answers" this is an ambiguous question/assignment which makes it really bad for beginners.

Comment: I do not see any errors in the answers except that question 2 is flawed. Creating a “double-free” error requires passing the same pointer value to `free` twice. However, once the memory a pointer points to is freed, the pointer value becomes indeterminate (C 2018 6.2.4 2). Then it could be a trap representation (3.19.2), so even using it may cause a trap, for which the behavior is undefined. So it cannot be passed to `free` again without risking undefined behavior, which violates a condition of the question. However, the instructor may be unaware of this.

Comment: For the first one I'd have e,f,g,h,a,b, _d,c_ as opposed to you _c,d_ since after freeing, assign `nullptr` (should be `NULL` actually since this is C ideally) to `q` then assign it to `p` so that both have `NULL` to avoid any chance of UB by using it later (provided there are NULL checks later before accessing it)

Comment: " e,f,g,h,a,b,c,d" is incorrect as `p = q;` after `q` has been freed causes undefined behaviour , as the previous comment points out, it could end in "d,c" instead or go with your other solution. The others look ok to me -- in part 2, you don't use a pointer after freeing  (assigning new value to point variable does not use the old value)